# HTML5. How to make a full-width and height video inside a div block?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Right now i have the situation on photo.

[Stories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVqbo.png)

[image]

I need that, regardless of whether the video is vertical or horizontal, it completely covers the DIV block of the circle from the inside.

That is, so that there is no white stripe on top if it is a horizontal video and so that there are no white stripes on the left and right if it is a vertical video.

And when you click on the video, the player displays the clip without zoom.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Stories_line">
  <li>
      <video controls="" width="130px" height="130px" autoplay="" class="stories">
  <source src="video/Stories1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/Stories1.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video/Stories1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <object data="video/Stories1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="video.swf">
  </object>
</video>
 </li>
<!-------------------->
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Stories_line {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stories {
    background: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570) border-box;
    color: #313149;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

ul.images li {
    display: inline;
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

```
    <div class="Stories_line">
<!---------------------->
  <li>
 <div class="Stories_circle">  
      <video controls="" autoplay="" class="User-stories-video" muted="">
  <source src="video/Stories1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/Stories1.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video/Stories1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <object data="video/Stories1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="video.swf">
  </object>
</video>
</div>   
 </li>

<!------------------->

<!----->

<!-------------------->
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.Stories_line {
        display: flex;
        gap: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
     
.Stories_circle {
    background: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570) border-box;
    color: #313149;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.User-stories-video {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.9);
    -o-transform: scale(1.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.9);
    transform: scale(1.9);
}
```